# InBuilt Web Cam not working in HP Laptop. As I open cheese it shows complete black screen. Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: hp, webcam, cheese

My HP Pavilion laptop has Ubuntu 18 version and I once tried to disable InBuilt webcam just for security reasons. But now it wasn't working and I reinstalled newer version of Ubuntu 20. But even after installing newer version the camera is still not working.

When I open cheese it shows this screen.[image]

I assumed I might have deleted the drivers as I was doing package installation and removel that time.

Please suggest me what should I do to get this working.

Comment: any luck in solving the problem?